What is Lee holding in her hands in Longlegs?
In the movie, Longlegs, FBI agent Lee goes back to her mom and cooks for her.
When she is in the kitchen, she notices a box of items wrapped in plastic bags next to a few synringes, as we can see in this screenshot below,

Agent Lee speaks to herself "Jesus Christ, mom" while holding a bag of items in her hands.
It is well-established that her mom is a hoarder, stocking all kind of items in her house and Longlegs is using them to build cursed dolls.
What items are these in this small plastic bag?

I think the implication that it is drugs is pretty clear.

@Paulie_D, they appear to be human teeth, no? Or is it just me.

Or rocks of crack? I haven't seen the movie so I'm not sure.
